# Multiple Data Types with Vectors of Vectors

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, types

I am trying to find a way to create a 3 dimensional vector with three different types, such that it is structured as:

```
Vector[long][int][double];
```

I have found plenty of examples that show how to create a 3d vector with a single data type, such as:

```
std::vector<vector<vector<int> > >;
```

But I can now find or figure out how to assign multiple data types to the vector.

Comment: You can't do that. Your second declaration mimmicks a 3D array, true, but vectors don't have dimensions. They hold elements of one type in a single block of memory. And anyway, what would `vec[3.14]` mean?

Comment: Can you further describe your desired structuring? What you've provided doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conceptually `Vector[long][int][double]` doesn't make any sense. You can have a vector of vectors of vectors of *something*. There's only 1 type of *something* in the end.

Take a step out of dimensionality. If you're just trying to contain 3 values per element in a vector you can do that a number of ways. Make a vector of a type that contains your 3 values: your own struct probably.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction; I will start working on making my own struct.

Answer (score 4):

You should use a struct if you wish to use all three types at the same time.

```
struct Vector3d{
  long x;
  int y;
  double z;
};
//... or a union, if each entry only contains one type.
union NumberContainer
{
  long x;
  int y;
  double z;
};
std::vector<Vector3d> vector1;//Vector of three types
std::vector<NumberContainer> vector2;//Vector that can contain one of three types per entry
vector1[0].x=1;
vector1[0].y=2;
vector1[0].z=3;
//vector1 contains... x=1, y=2,z= 3
vector2[0].x=1;
vector2[0].y=2;
vector2[0].z=3;
//vector2 contains x=undefined, y=undefined, z=3
```

Comment: @DeadMG Whats your reasoning? Because there is a magnitude of reasons why boost:variant would be a poor choice.

Comment: +1 to counteract DeadMG's -1... nice to mention `boost::variant`, but still completely reasonable to mention unions. Separately, such a strange question... perhaps the real need is for a `vector<vector<vector<NumberContainer> > >`, but I can't be sure from reading the Q.

Comment: Unions are unsafe. That's why `boost::variant` should always be the default, rather than a union.

Comment: @DeadMG If you bother to use just a little bit of precaution, unions aren't any more unsafe than the rest of C++. On the other hand, boost::variant adds a huge amount of runtime and compile time overhead for some incredibly basic functionality. Not to mention an extra dependency. Yes it has its uses. But this is not one of them.

Comment: Yours `std::vector` are empty: you can access the first three elements because they doesn't exist. Use `push_back()`or `resize()` instead.

Comment: @R. M. I know that. It also doesn't contain a main function or includes... its an abridged example.

Comment: @RTS I imagined you know that and I've seen that there is no `main()` function. But putted like this is maybe confusing for someone that use `std::vector`for the first time. ;) My comment was just to clarify this point.

Comment: Well, actually, unions can be quite a bit more unsafe than well-written C++, and `boost::variant` solves this just fine. It's run-time overhead is not, in fact, "huge" at all. The ability to determine the contained type, and visitation, and never-empty guarantee, are well worth the price. Compared to the "I hope I got it right *every single time I use it* else good chance of UB" union..

Comment: @DeadMG, So, you wrap it in a struct, with a type id. Provide automatic conversion between types. You only have to get it right once.

Answer (score 2):

At the end of the day, your data structure has to hold  *something* , and that something can only be of one type.  Now, if you want to store multiple data types in each location of your vector, your "something" can itself be a struct of multiple different types.

It would help if you provided a little more context